# Records getting duplicated when mapped to object in TemplateContext.Database.SqlQuery function

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ado.net, template-context

I am getting strange issue when I am calling a stored procedure like this using `TemplateContext`

```
string query = "exec SearchRequest @recct = @TotalCount OUTPUT" + parametersString.ToString();
var requestDtos = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<RequestDto>(query, totalCount).ToList();
```

This gets sometimes 30 and sometimes 60 objects in `requestDtos` while the database is actually returning correct number of rows based on `PageSize` parameter that I am passing to the stored procedure, but strangely records are getting duplicated while getting mapped to objects.

So instead of getting 10 objects if page size is 10 I am getting duplicated 30 or 60 objects.

Any idea of this strange behavior?

Comment: I think you need to do `.Take(10)` after `.Distinct()` like `.Distinct().Take(10).ToList();`

Comment: I updated my question, actually I tried calling distinct because of that duplicate object behavior, it was not in the original code. The issue is it shouldn't actually duplicate the objects.

Comment: Then you can try like this `(query, totalCount).Take(10).ToList();`

Comment: But why should I do that workaround? The issue is why it is making records 30 or 60 when database is returning only 10 records. It should work directly with this `ctx.Database.SqlQuery<RequestDto>(query, totalCount).ToList();` only

Comment: I mentioned in the question that when I run the same query in the database that is getting passed to the code it returns correct no. of rows. So the same query returns 10 records when I run it through sql server management studio and in code after mapping records are getting duplicated.

Comment: We can't check if your `SearchRequest` procedure is any good. It's probably got a join that sometimes duplicates data.

Comment: I am checking the same query that is coming in `query` variable on the same time. It is returning proper result.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing parameters correctly. I suggest you to use below code :

```
var outParam = new SqlParameter();
outParam.ParameterName = "TotalCount";
outParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
outParam.ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Output;

var requestDtos = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyType>("SearchRequest @recct, @TotalCount OUT", 
               new SqlParameter("recct", parametersString.ToString()), 
               outParam);
var result = requestDtos.ToList();
var totalCount = (int)outParam.Value;
```

Comment: I am passing the variables in the same way. I posted only two lines of my code, I am doing the same thing in my code. If I would not do that it would throw an exception. It is running that means I am passing everything properly.